# Rails remote javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my views I have recently started implementing remote javascript updates of only parts of my pages using commands such as:

```
$("#flash_messages").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'shared/flash_messages') %>");
```

I now have a scenario where I have a list of items, each one within  tags with a unique id and when the user clicks on a link within an item I want to only replace the contents of the corresponding

i.e.

```
<span id="article-123">
  html here
</span>
```

create.js.erb

```
$("#???????").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'shared/article') %>");
```

My question is how to I pass the span id "article-123" through to my create.js.erb file and include it as a variable in the above command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `locals` variable in render response, in `YourController#method`

```
  respond_to do |format|
   format.js { render "create", :locals => {:article_id => article_id} }
  end
```

now you can use `article_id` in create.js.erb file.